# Enable multiple BLE Characteristic notifications in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have tried to enable the 2 notification in my UWP application, But every time only first characteristic notify user.

```
    AccessConfigurationCharacteristic();
                ConfigurationselectedCharacteristic = selectedCharacteristic;
                CharacteristicNotifyEnableForConfig();

                await Task.Delay(5000);

                AccessDiagnosticCharacteristic();
                DiagnosticselectedCharacteristic = selectedCharacteristic;
                CharacteristicNotifyEnable();

  private async void CharacteristicNotifyEnable()
        {
            try
            {
                // BT_Code: Must write the CCCD in order for server to send notifications.
                // We receive them in the ValueChanged event handler.
                // Note that this sample configures either Indicate or Notify, but not both.
                var result = await
                        DiagnosticselectedCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
                            GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
                if (result == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                {
                    AddValueChangedHandler();
                    // rootPage.NotifyUser("Successfully registered for notifications", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
                }
                else
                {

                    //  rootPage.NotifyUser($"Error registering for notifications: {result}", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                // This usually happens when a device reports that it support notify, but it actually doesn't.
              //  rootPage.NotifyUser(ex.Message, NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
```

'CharacteristicNotifyEnableForConfig()' method is similar to CharacteristicNotifyEnable() but with different characterstic.Can anyone help me to solve.

Comment: If you enable one characteristic notification at a time, both of them works?

Comment: No..If you enable one characteristic notification, one will work, If you enable two characteristic notification, only one will work. i.e, First one from two characteristic .

Comment: I test with TI cc2650 Sensor Tag and I can enable two characteristics notifications and I can receive both of their value changed events. What's your BLE device? Do you mind showing your complete code?

Comment: I am using rn4871 ble device.i';; attach more code

Comment: Thanks!!i'll send mail